# return One-To-Many join results as arrays in an object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, one-to-many, dql

I have a table for posts and another table with reply posts. I have a One (post) to Many (reply posts) relation mapped in doctrine correctly. I can join the two and get what i'd expect, an array of arrays for each reply, but the content from the original post is the same. Is it possible to return a single array/object for each post with the reply contents in an array?

Here's what i get now (as expected):

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'content' => string 'Test homework post' (length=18)
      'replyContent' => string 'this is a reply' (length=15)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'content' => string 'Test homework post' (length=18)
      'replyContent' => string 'second reply' (length=12)
```

I want something like this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'content' => string 'Test homework post' (length=18)
      'replyContent' => 
                   array (size = 2)
                       0 => 'replyContent' => string 'this is a reply' (length=15)
                       1 => 'replyContent' => string 'second reply' (length=12)
```

I've done my best researching, but have only come across results regarding returning arrays instead of objects. Maybe it isn't possible, but I thought it might be considering one-to-many relation mapping in the php classes define:

```
$this->[name for protected variable] = new ArrayCollection();
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Edit: This is my doctrine query:

```
        SELECT
            homeworkPost.content,
            homeworkPostReplies.content AS replyContent
        FROM AcmeMainBundle:HomeworkPost homeworkPost
        LEFT JOIN homeworkPost.homeworkPostReplies homeworkPostReplies 
        WHERE homeworkPost.course = :course
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem and found the solution so i am leaving this as reference:
piece of the code i am using

```
    $query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query->select("partial venue.{id,name,description,state,city,street,postalCode,lon,lat},partial r.{id}")
    ->from("CoreBundle:ServiceProvider","venue")
    ->join("venue.reviews","r","with","IDENTITY(r.serviceProvider) = venue.id")
    ->andWhere("venue.city = :city_name")
    ->andWhere("IDENTITY(venue.venueStatus) != 1")
    ->andWhere("IDENTITY(venue.venueStatus) != 3")
    ->setParameter("city_name",$cityName)
    ->orderBy("venue.points" ,"DESC")
    ->addOrderBy("venue.name" ,"ASC");
```

using partial will solve this problem
reference [14. Doctrine Query Language — Doctrine 2 ORM 2 documentation - 14.2.4.1. Partial Object Syntax](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** now that DQL is posted.

Do this:

```
SELECT
    homeworkPost.content,
    homeworkPostReply.content
FROM AcmeMainBundle:HomeworkPost homeworkPost
LEFT JOIN AcmeMainBundle:HomeworkPostReply homeworkPostReply 
WHERE homeworkPost.course = :course
```

You need to be joining to the HomeworkPostReply entity

---

If you're doctrine result is correct then

```
$qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

should resolve your problem.

You could also process the result data post query:

```
$result = array();

$formatResult = function($post, $k) use (&$result)
{
    $found = false;
    for($i = 0, $count = count($result); $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        if($result[$i]['content'] == $post['content'])
        {
            $found = true;
            if(!isset($result[$i]['replyContent']))
            {
                $result[$i]['replyContent'] = array();
            }
            $result[$i]['replyContent'][]= $post['replyContent'];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found){
        $result[] = array('content'=>$post['content'],
                'replyContent'=>array($post['replyContent']));
    }
};

array_walk($originalResult, $formatResult);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: I tried getArrayResult() before and it doesn't give me what I want (it returns the same thing). I could process the data post query, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to. Thanks for the processing code though

Comment: see this for help with changing your query to work with get array result. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/TLoGufvdP-c

Comment: I looked at the link, but that isn't my problem. My getArrayResult isn't just returning the first entry (like in the link). it looks identical to my getResult() as i show above.

After doing more research, is it possible that what I'm looking for requires a custom hydration mode?

Comment: Post your query builder. I think your problem is there.

Comment: Yep.  Post the query.  You should be doing something like SELECT FROM post LEFT JOIN reply.  But it looks like you are doing SELECT FROM reply LEFT JOIN post.

Comment: @james_t. I tried using your query. I get the same result as before. an array of size 2 with two arrays inside with repeating "content". Any other suggestions?

Comment: try selecting `homework` only, but leave the rest of the query the same.